# Different color in different applications

Tags: display, colors, gimp

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.

I needed to do some image editing (changing a background color). Opened up Gimp and changed it.

But when opened in a browser, or the image viewer the color is different.

Here's an example:
This is how the color looks in Gimp

[image]

And this is how it looks in a browser, image viewer...

[image]

In the Gimp the color looks more pale than red (how it's supposed to look and) in the browser it looks more saturated.

---

pomsky here are my video details:

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:40 memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d6100000-d613ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Remember that each browser behaves slightly differently on many parameters, try checking other browsers.

Comment: George. Totally forgot about that. In Firefox the color is like in Gimp. Weird...

Comment: Leon, look this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/62097/gimp-colours-do-not-fill-correctly